# How to speed up my simple sql query

Tags: sql, subquery

```
select id,firstname,lastname,email,country,portal,language 
from totaluser 
where userid in 
    (select user from (select user, shipping / NULLIF(goodsvalue,0) as difference 
    from shipment 
    where user in 
        (select user 
        from (select user, count(*) as shipcount 
        from shipment 
            where user in 
            (select user from shipment 
            where status in ('3','5') 
            and createdtime between '2012-01-01' 
            and '2013-02-22' group by user) 
            and status in ('3','5') group by user) 
            as a 
        where status in ('3','5') 
        and shipcount=1)) 
    as b 
    where difference > 2.5);
```

I understand this is a very simple statement and its instantly in my testing server, however it takes forever to run in my production server. How should I change it to speed it up?

Comment: left out the RDBMS ....

Comment: The many subqueries would probably benefit from well-chosen indexes. Can you post additional information about your production DB?

Comment: As Silver Quettier indicated, what are the differences between your dev and production server? Are the indexes the same? SQL server version etc...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select tu.id, tu.firstname, tu.lastname, tu.email, tu.country, tu.portal, tu.language 
from totaluser tu, 
(select user 
     from shipment 
     where status in ('3','5') 
     and createdtime between '2012-01-01' 
     and '2013-02-22' and status in ('3','5')
     group by user 
     HAVING count(*) = 1 AND shipping / NULLIF(goodsvalue,0) > 2.5) s
where tu.userid = s.user;
```

I have tried to remove your nesting of subqueries which you were creating from the shipment table and created a collection of object which joins with the totaluser table.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks very messy. If I understand it correctly, it's doing this:

```
SELECT id,firstname,lastname,email,country,portal,language FROM totaluser LEFT JOIN
(SELECT user,COUNT(*) AS shipcount FROM shipment
 WHERE
    createdtime BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-02-22' AND
    status IN ('3','5') AND
    shipping / NULLIF(goodsvalue,0) > 2.5
    GROUP BY user) AS condid
ON totaluser.id=condid.user
WHERE condid.shipcount = 1;
```

(You can use [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/068b3/1) to test if I'm right)

I recomend you use [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) to index column `user` on `shipment`, and in general create also an index for any other column involved on a where clause (id,status and createdtime). That should speed up select queries on big tables (but slow down writings, so if you app is write intensive you must find a compromise).